# Unable to detect cdrom during Kali installation

Tags: mount, usb, kali-linux, system-installation

I am trying to install the latest Kali version on my laptop:

1. Got the official ISO [from docs.kali.org](https://docs.kali.org/introduction/download-official-kali-linux-images)
2. Created bootable Kali USB using Win32 Disk Imager
3. Booted the target machine from USB and got through until the point where the graphical installation complains about not being able to read from CD-ROM
4. Followed instructions in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/962993)
5. The graphical installation still isn't able to read from the CDROM

There are two suggestions in the answer mentioned above:

1. Unplugging USB

   > when the Window shows CDROM couldn't be mounted ,
   >
   > 1. Unplug your USB from system and re insert it
   > 2. wait for mount/ detection (usb LED glow)
   > 3. Hit Continue

This doesn't solve the issue of not being able to read from CDROM. The only thing I recognized is that the `sdb1` item in the `/dev` folder has gone for good.

2. Mount the USB as CDROM

   ```
   mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /cdrom
   ```

   I tried that, although I did not create a `cdrom` directory in root as it was already present.

   So what I get here is:

   ```
   mount: mounting /dev/sdb1 on /cdromfailed: Device or resource busy
   ```

I am pretty new to the Linux world, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're more likely to get useful help if you more accurately describe what happens.  Vague symptoms like “Nothing works” and “This doesn’t work at all” are almost impossible to diagnose.

Comment: @G-Man Edit: Replaced ambiguous symptom description. Although imo I did describe what exactly the symptoms are.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/315221/117549 sounds similar

Comment: Regarding "I am pretty new to the Linux world", please refer to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me#399627.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if you found a solution.. but here's how I solved it.
Use 'rufus' to write the iso image to USB .. and make sure you write the image to USB in DD mode and not the ISO mode.
This would make the USB as LIVE USB with no scope of adding anymore files besides the image as contrary to ISO mode.
Now once the USB with the KALI image is ready .. boot up and start installation .. you wont have any issue with detecting and mounting CD ROM

Comment: But why do we need need dd mode?